# Why's a call option called 'call', and put option called 'put'?

Tags: etymology, finance

I'm asking about etymology, and not [what these options are](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/7smiok/eli5_what_are_people_in_the_stock_exchange/dt6qyuo/). The answers beneath don't feel convincing; can't 'call' and 'put' be interchanged in them? I'll abbreviate Call Option to CO, and Put Option to PO. From [Quant SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/33349/31928):

> Not as much on origin of this, but some analogy that I find helpful:
>
> **Call** - think of an open auction when bidders call out their prices for an auctioned item. So with a call option you've got a privilege to
>   *call the strike price*, effectively having a right **to buy** the underlying asset.
>
> **Put** - think that you own a privilege to *put the asset for sale at the strike price*, effectively having a right **to sell** the
>   underlying asset.
>
> Mind that for an option buyer this is optional to exercise it, yet for
>   the option writer it's an **obligation** to transact, should the buyer
>   opt to exercise it.

But can't I be said to:

1. for a CO, "put" (to the CO seller) to buy the security at the strike price (for a CO)?
2. for a PO, "call" (to the CO seller) to sell the security at the strike price?

From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-call-option-called-as-such-as-opposed-to-a-put-option-What-is-the-etymology-behind-such-names#):

> When you buy a call and exercise it you are receiving stock that you have "called" up from the person that sold you the call, the right to buy.
>   When you buy a put you have purchased the right to sell the stock, or "put it" to the person who sold you the put.

Again, can't I say that a:

3. CO is when a CO seller "puts" the call option to the CO buyer?
4. PO is when a PO buyer is "calling" the PO seller to buy the security from the buyer?

Comment: To some extent, the answer is simply "that's the way those concepts came to be named." The sense of *put* as a venture or attempt is attested from 1661 in the OED, of the option to sell assets at a certain price at a certain date from 1718. *Call* meaning a demand for payment is attested from 1673, and of the option to demand assets at certain price at a certain date from 1825. They could have called them flibbertygibbets, but traders value brevity.

Comment: If you sell a call option and cover it by purchasing the underlying, and the price of the underlying rises above the strike price, the holder of the call option can “call away” your underlying asset. This is a fairly natural usage of English.

Answer (score 4):

An option in this context is a right to do something, so it makes sense to describe the option in terms of that right: a Put option is the right to *put* (sell) a security and a Call option is the right to *call* (buy) a security.

There are two parties involved:

- the *option holder* has the right to exercise the option. They could have acquired the option by buying the option, or it might have been granted to them as part of their remuneration, etc.
- the counterparty to the option holder (I'll just call them the *counterparty* here) has an obligation to be the counterparty to the underlying transaction if the option holder exercises the option: the counterparty must buy whatever was Put and sell whatever was Called.

Since options have two parties, you can describe them from either perspective or even both. Let's consider Put options, which you propose to define (Q2, Q4) as the counterparty "calling" the option holder to buy the security from the option holder.

Although you can describe a Put as the counterparty's obligation to buy, the transaction isn't done at *their* option. The counterparty has no choice in the matter. If the option holder chooses not to sell, the counterparty can't "call" the security; and if the option holder chooses to sell, the counterparty can't refuse.

You can describe a Put as the option holder’s right to sell and the counterparty’s obligation to buy. However, the connotation of the word "option" is one-sided. The derivative belongs to the option *holder*; the transaction triggers at their option. As such, it makes sense to describe a Put option from the option holder's perspective: they hold an *option to sell* the underlying security.

Likewise, it makes sense to describe a Call option as the option holder's *option to buy* the underlying security.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answers questions 1-4?

Comment: I understood Q1-4 as proposals to consider the options from the perspective of the option seller (the one I’ve called the counterparty in my answer). My answer says that you *could*, but the trade is not done at *their* option. If I’ve misunderstood your question, I apologise and request clarification.

Comment: very helpful answer.

"An option in this context is a right to do something, so it makes sense to describe the option in terms of that right:"

stood out a lot. it was always confusing to me before because i kept changing subconsciously who is the buyer/seller

The derivative belongs to the option holder; the transaction triggers at their option. As such, it makes sense to describe Put option from the option holder's perspective: they hold an option to sell the underlying security.

mmm very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

### For the etymology question in the title

English often adds a preposition to a verb to alter the meaning of a verb. *Calls* and *puts* should be understood from the perspective of the option writer, along with the corresponding prepositions "away" and "to."

I have written calls. My broker will report, "Your stock has been called away."  This is a shorthand for "Your (underlying) stock (on which the call was written) has been called away (and you have sold at the option's strike price to the option buyer)." (He could also say, "The call has been exercised" and hope that the option writer is well versed in the mechanics of options.) Here, the preposition *away* tells me the direction of the stock's motion: It is *away* from me, the call writer.

I have written puts. My broker will report, "The stock has been put to you." This is shorthand for "The put buyer has exercised his right to sell the underlying stock to you, the put writer, at the option's strike price." Here, the preposition *to* tells me the direction of the stock's motion: It is *to* me, the put writer.

Rather than cross-post my answer, here is a link to my answer on Quant.SE: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/33374/343 .

### For questions 1, 2, 3, and 4

The answers are no to all. You would be missing the underlying direction. For Q4, for example,

> Put Option buyer is "calling" the Put Option seller to buy the security from the buyer

While it might be understandable to the OP, this unconventional usage is using the inverse perspective (of the option buyer rather than the option writer). And note that the options exchange matches up option writers with option buyers; no one calls anyone on the phone.

The put buyer "puts the stock to" the put writer. Or colloquially, (because it forces the writer to buy a stock at the higher strike price rather than the current price), the put buyer "sticks it to" the put writer.

Comment: i appreciate this answer gets right to the point, while still answering the direct questions.  the post is really about one thing and the subsequent questions are intended to provoke the best response.

Comment: I could have invoked "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" (hat tip Noam Chomsky). *"Put" to buy the security at the strike price* is syntactically correct but has no meaning in the financial domain. But I thought it better to just use a first-person story.

Answer (score 0):

A call option is a financial security. A put option is a financial security. They each have a buyer and a seller. To answer your questions, think of it like this: The financial security owner is always the party who has control. **Only the owner can initiate action.** That must be your frame of reference. In other words:

**The owner is always the buyer.**
**The owner is never the seller.**

Answers to each of your four questions follow from that.

**Q1**. Can it be said that the call option seller "puts" to buy the security at the strike price?
**A1**. **No** it cannot. *By definition******, the **buyer/owner of the call option** is **exercising his right to buy** shares of the underlying stock at the call option strike price. (It is his right, as owner, to do so, but not his obligation, e.g. he can let the option expire worthless, or sell it to someone else prior to maturity should he wish.) The **seller of the call option** is passive. She collected the premium, i.e. the money paid by the buyer/owner for the call option at the time of purchase.

**Q3**. Can it be said that a call option is when a call option seller "puts" the call option to the call option buyer?
**A3**. **No** it cannot. The call option seller can't do anything to the call option buyer/owner. The seller has already been paid by the call buyer/owner. She (the seller) is contractually obligated to the call buyer/owner. There is nothing voluntary about it. Only the call option buyer/owner has a choice of whether to exercise his option or to allow it to expire. In the latter case (expiry), she (the seller) gets to keep his (the buyer/owner's) money. See the answer to Q1.

**Q2**. Can it be said that the put option buyer "calls" to the call option seller to sell the security at the strike price?
**A2**. **No, because you are confusing put options and call options.** They are two different instruments. A put option buyer (or seller) has nothing to do with a call option seller (or buyer). To quote you,

> "for a PO, "call" (to the CO seller) to sell the security at the
> strike price?"

A put option contract has a buyer and seller. A call option contract has a buyer and seller. **Those are FOUR DIFFERENT PEOPLE** (counterparties).
If you meant to ask whether the put option buyer "calls" to the put option seller to  sell the security at the strike price, **the answer is yes**. See the answer to Q4.

**Q4**. Can it be said that a put option is when a put option buyer is "calling" the put option seller to buy the security?
**A4**. **Yes**, but your terminology won't be understood by anyone else other than readers of your question here on StackExchange. To make an analogy with mathematics, your notation is non-standard and opaque. For purposes of understanding the concept you are correct. The put option buyer/owner exercises her right (but not obligation) to sell the put option contract at the strike price. The put option seller has no choice in the matter. He has already collected his money, and must do what he contractually agreed upon.

---

Your question has multiple parts. Regarding etymology of call and put: They are naming conventions. The comment by Choster is correct:

> "The sense of put as a venture or attempt is attested from 1661 in the
> OED, of the option to sell assets at a certain price at a certain date
> from 1718. Call meaning a demand for payment is attested from 1673,
> and of the option to demand assets at certain price at a certain date
> from 1825."

*****  **Option** is an informal way of describing an **options contract**. A noun cannot arbitrarily be turned into a verb in the context of legal terms. Options contracts are contractually defined.

**Note well**: **This answer pertains to options only**. Bonds (e.g. debentures, senior debt, convertibles) can be puttable and callable. That is out of scope for English Language & Usage SE. Money SE is the appropriate place for further questions.